# Is there anything I can add to an Apache server configuration file that will change the user of the PHP and apache processes?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache2

On my nginx server I can tell who is using up the resources. On my Apache server they all run as www-data. Is there anything that I can add to my apache site.conf files that will make it show the site name or user name in top?

Example of what it looks like on my Nginx server.
[image: On my nginx server is appears like this]

Comment: Other than php-fpm?

Comment: You do this the same way nginx does it: Don't use `mod_php` and switch over to `php-fpm` and `fcgi`. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM

Comment: @Sven Ok I followed the guide and installed PHP-FPM and now PHP-FPM appears as the command in TOP but the user still shows as www-data.